# QLineEdit resize method has no effect on construction?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class that inherits `QLineEdit` and in its constructors I call: `this->resize(30, 30);` and it has no effect, the line is utterly shrunk. If I call resize in some other method, it works fine. Just not in the constructor. It also doesn't work when called right after the object is constructed in the function where it's created. Is there some technicality I'm missing?

EDIT: changing the size policy to Ignored hides the widget completely

Comment: Show the code. If you're using layout managers they are changing the size.

Answer (score 2):

If your `QLineEdit` is inside a layout then the size of it will be determined by the owner layout. So if you want to make it exactly 30x30 then you should set the size policy of the line edit to [`Ignored`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) or you should set the minimum and the maximum size to desired one ([`minimumSize`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) same for `maximumSize`).

Comment: huh, it seems that method is private of QLineEdit and I can't call it from my class that inherit QLineEdit

edit: actually the constructor of QSizePolicy is private..

Comment: ok I used the constructor that takes 2 args with Ignored and now it doesn't show up at all

Comment: In that case try the other method. Set minimum and maximum size to the same value.